# Understanding spaces is the same as understanding (sheaves of) functions on the space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

I'm trying to understand Ravi Vakil's FOAG. In chapter 2 it is written:

> [...] understanding spaces is the same as understanding (sheaves of) functions on the spaces, and
> understanding vector bundles (a type of “space over M”) is the same as understanding functions

Can someone make this insight more obvious (manifest)? Maybe through some illuminating example or picture.

Comment: I guess, one way to interpret this is via the Gelfand-Neumark Theorem. Let $X$ be a locally-compact Hausdorff space, then X can be identified with the spectrum of the C* algebra A=C(X) and the vector bundles over X can be identified with finitely generated projective modules over A.

Comment: @Echo The GN theorem seems to be in a rather different context, though, since C(X) lacks certain properties one would usually want for coordinate rings of varieties, and is algebraically very "rigid"